# StringToWordVector in Weka

Tags: weka

What is StringToWordVector? All I know about it is that it converts a string attribute to multiple attributes. But what is the advantage of doing so and how an object of StringToWordVector class serves as a filter for FilteredClassifier? How has it become a filter?

Answer (score 1):

StringTOWordVector is the filter class in weka which filters strings into N-grams using WOrdTokenizer class. This helps us to provide strings as N-grams to classifier. Besides just tokenizing, it also provide other functionalities like removing Stopwords, weighting words with TFIDF, output word count rather than just indicating word is present or not, pruning rate, stemming, Lowercase conversion of words, etc. Detailed explanation of this class can  be found at http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVecing.html So Basically it provides basic functionalities which helps us to fine tune the training set according to requirements before training.

However, if someone, who wants to perform testing along with training, must use batchfiltering or Filtered classifier for ensuring compatability of train & test Set. This is because if we pass train & test separately through StringToWordVector then it will generate different vocabulary for train & test set. To decide which technique should be opted out of batch filltering & Filtered classifier, follow the post by Nihil Obstat at http://jmgomezhidalgo.blogspot.in/2013/01/text-mining-in-weka-chaining-filters.html

Hope this helps.